# Can "a" be removed in the follow case (noun + adjective + adjective)?

Tags: grammar, determiners

[Grammaly](https://grammarly.com) told me that the "a" in the following sentence is unnecessary and it suggested I remove it:

> The surface of the guitar was (a) gleaming white.

Is Grammaly correct? Why or why not?

*Note:* I searched for "surface was white" and "surface was a gleaming white." I got results in both cases.

*Update based on my comment below:*

To me, "was gleaming white" sounds like the object is casting a white gleam. "Was a gleaming white" sounds like the object is white, the gleaming type. Am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you think "a gleaming white" is correct in this context? I would say the *a* is optional but am curious if you have any specific reason for believing it should be there.

Comment: @Mixolydian To me, "was gleaming white" sounds like the object is casting a white gleam. "was a gleaming white" sounds like the object is white, the gleaming type. Am I wrong?

Comment: alexchenco I agree with what you're saying as well as @lorel-c's answer. "gleaming" does sound like it could be a verb without the "a".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, I don't think you should remove the article. "The surface of the guitar was **a** gleaming white." sounds fine to me: What kind of white was the guitar? It was a *gleaming* white. Nothing wrong with that, grammatically or idiomatically.

The sentence would also be ok without the **a**, but it could be momentarily confusing, as it makes "gleaming" sound like it could be a verb (with its subject being guitar), instead of a modifier of "white" -- like the guitar was "gleaming" or sparkling.

So I say, yes, you are right. Disregard Grammarly in this particular case.

Comment: "The surface of the guitar was pitch black", is equivelant to "The surface of the guitar was gleaming white", which is fine.